# Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gem

I am trying to install snorby, but I get this this error:

**Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources**

I tried to:

- Delete Gemfile.lock
- bundle install --no-deployment
- bundle install rake
- bundle update

It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next command:

`bundle install --path vendor/cache`